# ¿Por qué wampserver (mysql) no me permite agregar llaves foráneas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Las estructuras de mis tablas son las siguientes:

```
tabla cliente
 idCliente varchar(20)
 nombre varchar (25)
 apellidoPaterno varchar(30)
 apellidoMaterno varchar(30)
 rfc varchar(20)

 tabla favoritos
 idCliente varchar(20)
 idArticulo varchar(20)
 urlImagen varchar(100)
 nombreImagen varchar(60)
```

Y este es el script SQL para agregar la llave foránea del cliente.
Estos son los script que estoy ejecutando:

```
ALTER TABLE favoritos
ADD CONSTRAINT FavoritosidClienteFK FOREIGN KEY (idCliente) REFERENCES
cliente (idCliente) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE favoritos
ADD CONSTRAINT FavoritosidArticuloFK FOREIGN KEY (idArticulo) REFERENCES
articulo (idArticulo) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Y me marca el siguiente error:

```
MySQL ha dicho:
#1215 - No puede adicionar clave extranjera constraint.
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Como pueden darse cuenta los campos de idCliente tienen la misma longitud y el mismo tipo de dato.
NOTA: Ya agregué indice al campo idCliente de la tabla favoritos, pero aún así no me deja agregar foreign key.

Comment: ¿Es la única clave que estás agregando a tus tablas? Marca ahí como si tuvieras un error en tu código y estés tratando de dar de alta una restricción de la siguiente forma `ADD CONSTRAINT constraint`

Comment: NO, de hecho es la quinta clave foránea que estoy haciendo referencia

Comment: ¿Podrás poner todo el script completo de llaves foráneas que estás tratando de ejecutar? Ya que el que pones aquí está correcto

Comment: Ya edité mi pregunta, ahí escribí los dos script.

Comment: ¿Usas MyISAM como el motor de tu base de datos? de ser así no puedes usar llaves foráneas, ya que no las soporta, de ser así tendriás que cambiar a InnoDB

Comment: la tabla cliente es InnoDB, la tabla articulo es InnoDB, y la tabla favoritos es InnoDB, no sé por que no se pueden agregar

Comment: crees que sea por el cotejamiento de los datos? la tabla favoritos lo tengo como  utf8_general_ci

Comment: y las tablas cliente los datos los tengo como cotejamiento  latin1_swedish_ci  al igual que la tabla articulo, sus campos tambien con latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas.

Segun la [documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), no puedes definir claves como strings con distintos cotejamientos.

> When **foreign_key_checks** is enabled, which is the default setting, character set conversion is not permitted on tables that include a character string column used in a foreign key constraint.

Para solucionarlo puedes [hacer una de estas opciones]:

- Usar el mismo cotejamiento en todas las tablas relacionadas con claves.
- Cambiar tus claves primarias y extranjeras a `int`(que es mas eficiente) y trabajar los id como datos numéricos.
- Desactivar la comprobación de claves extranjeras con `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`

Comment: Gracias, me soluciono el problema